# Doing something different for main route in meteor iron router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Im using Iron-Route for routing in my meteor app. As I have multiple modules and I want to avoid multiple coding, I put the filter for authentification (role) to the core package:

**core package**

```
var filters = {
    authenticate: function () {
        var user;
        if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
            this.layout('login');
            this.render('loading');
        } else {
            user = Meteor.user();
            if (!user) {
                this.layout('login');
                this.render('signin');
                return;
            }
            this.layout('StandardLayout');
            this.next();
        }
    }
}
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
    before: filters.authenticate
});
Router.route('/', function () {
    this.render('contentTemplate', { to: 'content' });
    this.render('navigationTemplate', { to: 'navigation' },)
});
```

**other packages**

...just need this:

```
Router.route('/article/:_id', {
    name: 'article',
    yieldTemplates: {
        'navigationPage':   { to: 'navigation' },
        'contentPage':      { to: 'content' } 
    }
});
```

Now there is a check on every module (route) before displaying anything.
But I need an exception for the front page. The main page `Route.route('/')` should be accessed also by user who are not logged in. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onBeforeAction` hook from `iron:router` as shown below. 
This solution assumes your login route is named `'login'` .  But can be modified to fit your needs.

**./client/lib/hoooks/router.js**

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
    // all properties available in the route function
    // are also available here such as this.params
    if  (!Meteor.userId()) {
        //code for action to be taken when user is not logged in
        this.redirect('login');
        this.stop();
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
},{except: ['homeRouteName'] });
```

NB: Replace 'homeRouteName' with the name of your route at `'/'`

Comment: So I can put there the code which is now in the filter var, right?

Comment: I have not tried it, but you probably could.  The key is the `{except: ['routes']}` option which allows you to specify which routes do not run this hook.  Alternatively you could just `{only: ['routes']}` for the opposite effect.  I suggest except in your case since you only want it to not run on one.